# Error validation works on one form but not another (very similar form)

Tags: jquery, html, forms, validation, popup

I'm having trouble getting a form on my site to have proper validation upon submission (let's call it form #1). Validation currently **is** working on another form on my site (form #2). To clarify, form #2 correctly displays a red border around the fields upon an error, like so:

[image]

However, form #1 only displays the ugly default js validation like:

[image]

[Here is a link to my demo site.](http://taskbasket.net/public/demo1.html)

Form #1 (wrong) is accessed via the center link ("Launch Lightbox")
Form #2 (right) is accessed via top-right "Contact" link.

Both forms have virtually the same code, except their parent div is different because they're opened differently. **Here's form #1 (wrong) code:**

```
<aside class="lightbox">
  <input type="checkbox" class="state" id="lightbox-demo" />
  <article class="content">

    <main class="main">
    <a href="#" class="closest"><img src="img/x.png" class="btn_close" title="Close Window" alt="Close Contact Window" /></a>
  <form method="post" action="submit.php" id="contactform" class="signin">

        <input name="name" id="name" type="text" class="feedback-input" placeholder="Name" />
<input name="email" id="email" type="email" class="feedback-input" placeholder="Email" required pattern="[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+(?:[A-Z]{2}|com|org|net|edu|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|asia|jobs|museum)" required title="Whoops! Invalid email"/>
       <div class="antispam">
       <br /><input name="url" type="hidden" /></div>
       <textarea name="message" id="message" class="feedback-input" placeholder="Write away!" required minlength="15" required title="Must be at least 15 characters"></textarea>
        <button id="flybutton">
            <p>Submit </p>
            <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 512 512" enable-background="new 0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve">
                <path id="paper-plane-icon" d="M462,54.955L355.371,437.187l-135.92-128.842L353.388,167l-179.53,124.074L50,260.973L462,54.955z
M202.992,332.528v124.517l58.738-67.927L202.992,332.528z"></path>
            </svg>
        </button>
</form>
    </main>
    <footer class="footer">
      <button class="button" type="button">Do something</button>
    <label id="lightbox-demo-close" class="button" for="lightbox-demo">Close</label>
    </footer>
  </article>
  <label class="backdrop" for="lightbox-demo"></label>
</aside>
```

Here's form #2 (right) code:

```
<div id="login-box" class="login-popup">
<a href="#" class="closest"><img src="img/x.png" class="btn_close" title="Close Window" alt="Close Contact Window" /></a>
  <form method="post" action="submit.php" id="contactform" class="signin">

        <input name="name" id="name" type="text" class="feedback-input" placeholder="Name" />
<input name="email" id="email" type="email" class="feedback-input" placeholder="Email" required pattern="[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+(?:[A-Z]{2}|com|org|net|edu|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|asia|jobs|museum)" required title="Whoops! Invalid email"/>
       <div class="antispam">
       <br /><input name="url" type="hidden" /></div>
       <textarea name="message" id="message" class="feedback-input" placeholder="Write away!" required minlength="15" required title="Must be at least 15 characters"></textarea>
        <button id="flybutton">
            <p>Submit</p>
            <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 512 512" enable-background="new 0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve">
                <path id="paper-plane-icon" d="M462,54.955L355.371,437.187l-135.92-128.842L353.388,167l-179.53,124.074L50,260.973L462,54.955z
M202.992,332.528v124.517l58.738-67.927L202.992,332.528z"></path>
            </svg>
        </button>
</form>
<div id="result"></div>

</div>
```

calling on     `<script src="js/jquery.validation.js"></script>`

Can you spot the problem? Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have 2 elements with the same id, ID of an element must be unique.

So use different ID for those elements, and then you need to initialize the plugin for both the elements

```
<div id="login-box" class="login-popup">
    <a href="#" class="closest"><img src="img/x.png" class="btn_close" title="Close Window" alt="Close Contact Window" /></a>
    <form method="post" action="submit.php" id="contactform2" class="signin">
```

then move the plugin initialization to dom ready handler(line 515)

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $("#contactformm, #contactform2").validate({
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            fly(form);
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: Thanks Arun, but are you saying that I should do 3 steps:  1) Replace the second form's id from contactform to contactform2, 2) add #contactform2 to the validation code as you stated, and 3) add $(document).ready(function() { to the script?    This seems to have caused *both* forms to display errors incorrectly now. Please see my updated demo here:  http://taskbasket.net/public/demo1.html   Thank you

Comment: @Nova the changes are not reflected in the site

Comment: You may need to perform a "hard reset"  CTRL + F5, I can see them on my end. Line 521 shows me   <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
        var $btn = $('#flybutton');
        $("#contactform #contactform2").validate({ ....

Comment: @Nova Sorry... `$("#contactform, #contactform2")` missing `,` in the selector

Comment: I've updated the code. However when you incorrectly fill in the "Lightbox" form (center screen).. it simply submits and doesn't show any errors....

Comment: I've solved it by removing the form with id=contactform altogether, I only need contactform2 to work.. So thanks a lot! Saved me some serious headache.